# Do I need a paid apple developer account to connect Firebase to Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to learn through Youtube tutorials with Xcode. I had an idea for an app that should be able for people to create an account so I wanted to use Firebase for this. I followed all of the steps but I got an error saying "Failed to download settings. If this is your first time launching the app, make sure you have enabled Crashlytics in the Firebase Console.". I tried searching on the web for solutions but I think that Firebase isn't connecting to Xcode because I don't have a paid developer Apple account.
Can someone please confirm this? [this is a screenshot from XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2fTQ.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You only need a free account but you must ensure the bundle id is unique; don't rely on anything from a sample project. Firebase is unrelated to the error you have. It is a google product. Are you trying to run on a real device or the simulator. Have you added you free account login details to Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You do ***not*** need a paid developer account. Try using a simulator instead of a physical device when running your app.